# Prettier: How to intervene correctly?

Tags: typescript, rules, prettier

Prettier changes the code (A) into (B), and I would like to keep (A); how can I achieve that?

**(A)**

```
let whatEverNo = this.messages.length > 0 
  ? this.messages.length - 1 
  : 0;
```

**(B)**

```
let whatEverNo =
  this.messages.length > 0 ? this.messages.length - 1 : 0;
```

**EDIT:** please do not answer with `// prettier-ignore` :)

I'm looking for a better solution like changing the behavior via some secret magic tricks I do not know yet. I can remember, someone did it somehow somewhere, and unfortunately, I missed writing it down.

Comment: Have you tried `// prettier-ignore`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm looking for a better solution like changing the behavior via some secret magic tricks I do not know yet :)

Comment: If you mean configure prettier according to code pattern - this is not possible: _An opinionated code formatter_

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is also clear to me. I can remember, someone did it somehow somewhere, and unfortunately, I missed writing it down.